# Append a partial with onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have my onclick event working but when it comes to displaying the partial it:

only displays the text:

```
<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => payment)) %>
```

I want it to fetch the parial and display it

here is my code:

```
$(".payment").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => payment)) %>");
```

tried with "" and '' around payment

full jquery code for this

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.plans').change ->
    $(".payment").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'payment')) %>");
```

edit:

this worked for me if anyone looks at this in the future since i use devise:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'registrations/toggle_partial' => "registrations#toggle_partial"
  end
```

put the toggle_partial.js file in

```
views/devise/registrations
```

everything else that NickM put there is great....

also remember the '' around the partial name

Comment: Open page sourse Ctrl+U and check what HTML has got rendered there.

Comment: it just renders the words <%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => payment)) %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the 'full jquery' code you have above I'm guessing you have this in a coffeescript file, which does not have access to the render method.

You're going to have to set up a route that hits a controller action that renders the JS, like this:

routes.rb:

```
get 'controller_name/toggle_partial' => "controller_name#toggle_partial"
```

In that controller:

```
def toggle_partial
  respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

And in views/controller_name add a file called toggle_partial.js with these contents:

```
$(".payment").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => payment)) %>");
```

Then in your coffeescript file do something like this:

```
$('.plans').change ->
  $.ajax(
    type: 'GET'
    url: '/controller_name/toggle_partial'
    success: ( data, status, xhr ) ->
  )
```

Sorry if the indentation is off on the coffeescript example. The bottom line is that you don't have access to render in the coffeescript file so you have to make a work-around.
Hope this helps.

Comment: is there something missing in the coffeescript... i presume that it is an $.ajax call and you have a closing ) at the end

Comment: Oops, I did miss a line. Added the line and updated the answer. You're right, it's an ajax call, and you could do it on a click instead of a change event if you like :)

Comment: I have added an edit above if you could help me with the route for this either way i put it i get this error: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:179:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)

Comment: could it be get 'controller_name/toggle_partial' => "controller_name#toggle_partial"