# Ruby on Rails - Populate database record based on drop down selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm relatively new to Rails and creating my first app which is a quoting tool.

I have 3 tables I'm working with currently - Products, Orders, and Order_lines.  Products holds the current price of our products - including costs.  Orders hold the shell of the order, which will tie it eventually to a customer table.  The Order_lines hold all of the order_lines - and the view is populated based on the relationship and matching index between Order_lines and Orders.

The view, currently, also populates the prices using a join between the Products and Order_Lines.  However, this will not allow me to store historical data (if I change prices in the product table, then all of the order_lines previously created update with the new prices) - so what I would like is for a person to select the product from a drop down menu - and for the system to pull the current price/cost for that product - and add it to the order line.

Product table contains 4 columns labed: prod_nrc_cost, prod_nrc_price, prod_mrc_cost, prod_mrc_price

Order_lines table now has nrc_cost_line, nrc_price_line, mrc_cost_line, mrc_price_line.

When they select product 555 - I want it to lookup the price for product 555 in the products table - and fill those 4 prices in the corresponding columns in the Order_lines table, and save it.  It would be nice if I was able to populate it right on the page (giving the person the ability to adjust pricing if they want), and then send it to the controller to Save.

Does this make sense??

If I'm leaving anything out, please let me know.

**/orders/show.html.erb file**

```
<%= form_for(@order_line) do |f| %>

    <% if false %>
        <% if @order_line.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
                <h2><%= pluralize(@order_line.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order_line from being saved:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @order_line.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>


      <%= f.hidden_field :order_id, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :order_num, :value=>@order.order_num, class: 'form-control' %>
         <%= f.hidden_field :visible, class: 'form-control', :value=>true, :checked=>true %>

      <% if @order_lines.present? %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :line_num, :value=>@order_lines.maximum("line_num")+1, class: 'form-control' %>
        <% else %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :line_num, :value=>1, class: 'form-control' %>
        <% end %>



    <div class="row">

    <div class="field col-md-2 form-group">
        <%= f.label :Product %><br>
        <%= f.collection_select(:product_id, Product.all, :id, :prod_name, {:prompt => 'Select Product'},  {:id => 'product_id'}) %>
      </div>
       <div class="field col-md-2 form-group">
        <%= f.label :quantity %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
           <div class="field col-md-2 form-group">
        <%= f.label :NRC %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :nrc_price_line, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
     <div class="field col-md-2 form-group">
        <%= f.label :MRC %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :mrc_price_line, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>



       <div class="field col-md-2 form-group">
        <%= f.label :discount %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :discount, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
         <div class="field col-md-2 form-group">
        <%= f.label :notes %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :notes, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>


      <div class="actions col-md-2" style="padding-top:25px;">
        <%= f.submit "Add New Line", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**orders_controller.rb file**

```
    class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def orders
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @order_lines = @orders.order_lines
end


  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order_lines = @order.order_lines
    @order_line = OrderLine.new(:order_id=>params[:id])
    @product_categories = @order_lines.product

  end

def update_price
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end


  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json   
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end


  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:emp_id, :cust_id, :order_num)
    end
end
```

**order.rb Model**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :order_lines
    has_many :product_categories, through: :order_lines
    has_many :products, through: :order_lines
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add a data attribute to your product selector with the product_id

You could grab the price info on a change event for the dropdown:
In some Coffeescrript file:

```
$('.your_selector').change ->
  product_id = $(this).data('product_id')
  $.ajax(
  type: 'POST'
  url: "/product_price_finder"
  product_id: product_id
  success: ( data, status, xhr ) ->
  )
```

routes.rb

```
post "/product_price_finder/:product_id" => "products#update_price"
```

products_controller.rb

```
def update_price
  @product = Product.find(params[product_id:])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

in views/products/update_price.js

```
var product = $("#product_<%= @product.id %>")
// update the price with Javascript
```

Comment: lol - this reply made me realize how little I know about Rails - okay - let me try to mimic what you have here- and see what I can come up with.  Thanks for providing a direction, I'll let you know!

Comment: No problem. This should get you most of the way there, but you'll have to get creative with update_price.js. I might be able to help you further if you post the view where the products are displayed.

Comment: all of the work is done on the /orders/show.html.erb view  I've actually added that to the Original Post - try not to laugh too hard, I'm sure I've screwed up some best practices.

Comment: yeah I'm clueless - I can't get this to work at all - maybe if went through some tutorial on how to do this specific thing, I could apply it to my application.  I'm just not grasping how it works, which means I can't make changes to get it to work.

Comment: Yeah, the changes to the front end are relatively easy to implement, but updating prices in order lines might get tricky. A tutorial might be helpful. This is kind of a tall order for a SO question. I helped someone else with a similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537575/append-a-partial-with-onclick-event/26549640#26549640

Comment: okay I'll take a look at that - I figured this was going to be a bit much - so that's fine.  At this point, I'm probably just going to hire a developer to finish this damn application for me, I've been hung up on this single block for about 2 months now.

Comment: I think the place I'm really lost on, actually, if you don't mind shedding light - I think I understand the AJAX Post, and all that.  I don't understand where in your example code that the fields get updated.  I know you say "update the price with Javascript" but I think I'm lost on that part.

Comment: If you passed the order id to update_price you could do @order.update_prices and write a method that finds all the prices and updates. Hard to say without seeing the whole code base. Best of luck.